# How can I read information from a dataLayer, with javascript?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, cart, data-layers

```
Good morning people of stackoverflow :)
```

I am working on an e-commerce website. One of our tracking partners requires the setup of a 
function named "csAdd". This function reads the customer cart and then uploads information.

What I would like to display **for each line in the cart** is information following this template :

```
myTag.csAdd('Sku1', 
  'Sku1Quantity',
  '', 
  'Sku1Quantity*ItemSinglePrice', 
  'ItemSinglePrice', 
'');
```

Same for Sku2, Sku3, etc.

**The result*** would be the following :

```
<script>
  myTag.csAdd('136340026', 
  '2',
  '', 
  '90', 
  '45', 
'');

  myTag.csAdd('774595138', 
  '1',
  '', 
  '49.99', 
  '49.99', 
'');

</script>
```

Please note that some single quotes are empty, this is not an error, our tracking script needs empty quotes where information is not present (for example *item cost without VAT*).

***My problem** is : I don't know how to tell javascript "*for each line in the cart, please send me the information via csAdd*"

The information needed is already displayed in a dataLayer so I think javascript "could" read this :

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
  'pageTitle': 'BasketPage',
  'basketId': '2241121',
  'admincosts': '5,5',
  'basketTotal': '145.49',
   'basketProducts': [{
    'sku': '136340026',
    'name': 'Jean',
    'price': '90.00',
    'quantity': '2'
},{
    'sku': '774595138',
    'name': 'Jacket',
    'price': '49.99',
    'quantity': '1'
    }]
}];
</script>
```

But how can I proceed ? Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array dataLayer of json objects which contain property 'basketProducts' which is an array.
You need two for loops (one to each array).
In the second (nested) loop you call myTag.csAdd() method passing required properties values of each product in a basketProducts [bProd] array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.length; i++) {
    var bProd = dataLayer[i].basketProducts;
    for (var j = 0; j < bProd.length; j++) {
        myTag.csAdd(
                    bProd[j].sku,
                    bProd[j].quantity,
                    '',
                    bProd[j].quantity * bProd[j].price,
                    bProd[j].price,
                    ''
                    );
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some describing text to the listing you've provided.

Comment: Thank you EchoSin, I will test your piece of code and keep you informed :)

Comment: Unfortunately "undefined" is returned by this code. But I think it's a Google Tag Manager problem : I placed your code in a macro, and custom js macros require a "function" and a "return" statement to work. So I integrated your code into `function (blah) { ... }; return "blah"; }` and my "undefined" result is appearing in the cart source code.